# PHP form - retain textbox values on submit

Tags: php, forms, textbox

I have the following code for submitting a form - it doesn't do much at the moment but what I am looking to achieve is this:

The textbox `docTitle` is a required field.

If the `yourName` textbox has text in it and the `docTitle` textbox is left blank, when submitted the required field message appears and the `yourName` textbox retains it's value.

I'm struggling with the part where the form retains the previous values after submitting.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($docTitle)) {
    } else {
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000) && ($_POST["docTitle"] > "")) {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
            }
                else
            {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                if (file_exists("upload/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                }
                    else
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                    "upload/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid file";
        } 
    }
}
?>

<form name="uploadAPdf" id="uploadAPdf" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="text">Name: </label> <input type="text" name="yourName" id="yourName" /><br />
<label for="text">Document: </label> <input type="text" name="docTitle" id="docTitle" />
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($docTitle)) {
 echo " Document title must be filled in...";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.uploadAPdf.docTitle.focus();</script>";
} ?>
<br /> 
<label for="file">Select PDF to upload: </label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: from what i gather you essentially want to prompt the user if they have left a field blank? so what I ask is, why do it after submitting the form? why not use jquery or javascript to perform the check and prompt the user before submitting?

Comment: That's a fair point... and in this case that would work... I would still like to know how to make a form remember it's value after it has been submit though.

Comment: Whenever you do it, you **must** do it server side. **Please don't ever forget to check user input!!** Client side is fine, but **do it server side** as well. Got it? =)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want:

```
<?php
function postValue($name, $alt = '') {
  return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $alt;
}
?>
<label for="text">Name: </label> <input type="text" name="yourName" id="yourName" value="<?=htmlspecialchars(postValue('yourName'))?>" /><br />
<label for="text">Document: </label> <input type="text" name="docTitle" id="docTitle" value="<?=htmlspecialchars(postValue('yourName'))?>" />
```

That's (sort of) how most Forms work...

Maybe I'm missing something =)

**edit**
This is a function I used to use when I didn't use a PHP framework:

```
<?php
function ifsetor($var, $alt = '') {
  return isset($var) ? $var : $alt;
}
?>
```

which would be used like this:

```
<?php
$selectedOptions = ifsetor($_POST['options'], array());
?>
```

**edit**
Unrelated: you might want to put your form elements in a wrapper (instead of separating them with a `<br>`) like this:

```
<div class="form-element"><label>...</label><input .... /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your html input(s) code to:

```
 <input type="text" name="docTitle" id="docTitle" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['docTitle'];   ?>" />
```

Comment: Good catch: `htmlspecialchars` =) **edit** but you don't know if `$_POST['docTitle']` actually exists.

Comment: of course:  allways `htmlspecialchars` or equivalent and 'docTitle' is an example from @Tom code